# Developing Html5 and Mobile Games

Tags: android, html, mobile, game-engine

I am a very experienced developer specially with Java.  Recently I've used "Construct 2" from Scirra.com to create both Html5 and mobile games; I think "Construct 2" is just great; makes 2d game development so easy.  however, I don't think "Construct 2" is used by very experienced game developers.  So, my question is what tools are the most commonly used tools by professionals to develop Html5 and mobile games?

Thanks for answering my quesion

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 is still new, so there are a lot of emerging engines and development tools. Unfortunately, this means there are a lot of 'fly-by-the-night' engines that don't last long.

The two companies with the most funding to work with are [Game Closure](http://docs.gameclosure.com/) and [Turbulenz](https://turbulenz.com/), so those are making more of a push for the 'professional' game developer audience.

Funding doesn't always mean reliability however - they have more demand to reach for a higher exit for the company, and if they're not able to raise secondary rounds, they will be dead in the water.

An alternative suggestion would be something like [ImpactJS](http://impactjs.com), which, while developed primarily by one person, has been reliably updated over the course of 2 and a half years.

You can find more HTML5 game engine options [on this site](http://html5gameengine.com/) (full disclosure: I built it). It only lists the engines that have gained some traction, and are actively maintained - so hopefully you won't run into the issue of choosing one that stops development 6 months down the road.